# Check if all the elements of an array are in a string in a where clause in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a model that has a field `type` which consists of several words. The string looks like this: `modern premium hot`.

How to get relevant results if I want to filter it with an array like this one:

```
$filter = [0 => 'modern', 1 => 'hot'];

$search = implode(' ', $filter);

$results = Model::where('type', $search)->get();
```

The above example will not return anything because it will try to match `modern premium hot` with `modern hot` and its not the same, but how to get all relevant results that contain the words `modern` and `hot` at the same time in the `type` fields?

In other words how to get all results that have all elements of the array in the `type` field, which is a string?

Comment: Single database columns (here: your `type` column) aren’t designed to hold more than one value. I’ve done this multiple times and I’ve always run into problems like this. A separate model to hold your `Model`’s types, such as `ModelType`, which has a `type` field and `model_id` would solve this problem. If you don’t want to change it, you could use the [`LIKE` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp) or your database’s equivalent. This might still cause problems when you have types with the same prefix, such as `hot` and `hotel`.

Comment: @KevSlashNull Thank you. I usually do it like this, but this time was an exception and was stuck on how to make it work. I will definitely keep in mind the situation where `hot` might be part of works like `hotel` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a fulltext service like Elastic Search or Algolia, or even look at fulltext search on your database engine (assuming MySQL, check [this link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php)).

But if you really need to move on as it is going, you may try something like that:

```
$query = Model::query();

foreach ($filter as $term) {
    $query->orWhere('type', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%");
}

$results = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tested it out and worked. I will have this in mind for the fulltext service.

Answer (score 1):

You use `orWhere()`

```
$filter = [0 => 'modern', 1 => 'hot'];

$query= Model::query();
foreach($filter as $term) {
    $query->orWhere('type', $term);
}

$results = $query->get();
```

if you have other `where()` in your query, use this

```
$filter = [0 => 'modern', 1 => 'hot'];

$results = Model::where(function($query) use($filter) {
    foreach($filter as $term) {
        $query->orWhere('type', $term);
    }
})
//->where(....)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have other where clauses as well so this is absolutely helpful!